# What is the default advice kind when using <aop:advisor>?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

What is the default advice kind when using `<aop:advisor>`? Is it `around` or something else? I did not find much information in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-schema-advisors). Any link to more information? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the documentation says [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-schema-advisors):

> The advice itself is represented by a bean, and must implement one of the advice interfaces described in [Advice types in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api-advice-types).

Thus, it is your own choice which type of advice you want to implement in your advisor. It can be any of

- around,
- before,
- after returning,
- throws,
- introduction.